# Pandas slowness with dataframe size increased size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to remove all url from a column. The column has string format.
My Dataframe has two columns: `str_val[str], str_length[int]`.
I am using following code:

```
t1 = time.time()
reg_exp_val = r"((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+)"
df_mdr_pd['str_val1'] = df_mdr_pd.str_val.str.replace(reg_exp_val, r'')
print(time.time()-t1)
```

When I run the code for `10000` instance, it is finished in `0.6` seconds. For 100000 instances the execution just gets stuck. I tried using `.loc[i, i+10000]` and run it in `for` cycle but it did not help either.

Comment: Using your code, I am getting around 2s for 1M row DF of randomly generated URLs so can't explain your timing. A simpler regex should be possible [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331982) but does not explain your timing.

Comment: it is probably RAM. I would try convert the column to a list apply the reg-ex in the list and turn the back into df after processing. DataFrames have a large overhead.

Comment: @user19077881, yeah, I copied the RegExp from verified source (as I thought) but it got stuck for some if my code examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the reg exp I was using. The one, which worked for me was

```
r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]|\(([^\s()<>]|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))",
```

Which was taken from [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28185064/python-infinite-loop-in-regex-to-match-url)